# Video Embed issue in cake php 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cake php, i installed cakephp-video-helper-master helper plugin for embedding videos and in my bootstrap file i autoloaded that plugin like this `Plugin::load('VideoEmbed', ['autoload' => true]);`

My view file includes the line:

```
echo $this->Video->embed($video['Video']['https://www.youtube.com/embed/ms7M8q1UTVk']);`
```

It shows video is undefined as error.

**Error screen:**

[image: error screen]

**View**

[image: view file]

Comment: By the way: There is also https://github.com/dereuromark/MediaEmbed

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of [VideoEmbed](https://github.com/drmonkeyninja/cakephp-video-helper) is the video's URL (a `string`). So your call needs to look something like:-

```
echo $this->Video->embed('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ms7M8q1UTVk');
```

According to your error messages `$video` hasn't even been defined so you are not actually passing anything to the helper method. Make sure your `$video` variable is set in your controller and that the array value you are passing the `embed` method is a `string` URL. You're probably looking to do something like:-

```
if (!empty($video['Video']['url'])) {
    echo $this->Video->embed($video['Video']['url']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://github.com/drmonkeyninja/cakephp-video-helper):

```
// Usage
echo $this->Video->embed($video['Video']['url'], array(
    'width' => 450,
    'height' => 300,
    'failSilently' => true // Disables warning text when URL is not recognised
));
```

This should work:

```
echo $this->Video->embed('https://www.youtube.com/embed/ms7M8q1UTVk');
```

Comment: Correct answer, but for the wrong plugin! The plugin you linked to is for CakePHP 2, the one being referred to by the OP is mostly likely [VideoEmbed](https://github.com/drmonkeyninja/cakephp-video-helper) for which there are versions for both CakePHP 2 and 3.